# Translation: Doctor Rounds (doctor visiting patients in hospital)

Tags: traducción

When a doctor visits patients in a hospital setting, especially in a medical school affiliated hospital with medical student following, that is the "doctor rounds." What would be the common term for that in Latin Americas Spanish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ronda médica

> Conjunto de acciones prácticas que se debe desarrollar de manera habitual por el personal médico en los servicios de urgencias, observación y hospitalización, presentando de manera global el estado, manejo actual,
> evolución y procesos pendientes de cada usuario.

### Ronda hospitalaria

> Observación diaria que se hace a los pacientes integrados por médicos, enfermeros, estudiantes y personal.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions with the detailed usage information.  My wife heard a usage in a telenovela that used _vuelta_ as the key word in a phrase, but she couldn't remember the words used with it.  Could have been a slang phrase or a Mexico region specific.